# Contao CMS Query a 'checkboxWizard' BLOB field

Tags: mysql, blob, contao

I have a question about how to query a 'checkboxWizard' BLOB field. In have added a such field to tl_member. This is working very fine. I can add “0 to N” selection to each members. Let’s call this field “myBlob”.

Now the questions is how to query “myBlob” with the Contao way? Let’s say I want all member that are in the postal code “12120” and that have the id “2” of “myBlob” selected. Not only “2” but at least this one.

```
   $arrColumn[] = "tl_member.postal=?";
   $arrValues[] = 12120;

   $arrColumn[] = "tl_member.myBlob=?"; <- how to say “contains in the blob” here?
   $arrValues[] = 2;

   self::findBy($arrColumn, $arrValues)
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this (when using the default Contao method for such relationships) is to create a query like:

```
… WHERE myBlob LIKE '%"2"%'
```

So in your case it might be:

```
$arrColumn[] = "tl_member.myBlob LIKE ?";
$arrValues[] = '%"2"%';
```

However, this is of course cumbersome and might not work in all cases.

May be a better way would be to use [codefog/contao-haste](https://github.com/codefog/contao-haste) with its 'many to many' helper: https://github.com/codefog/contao-haste/blob/master/docs/Model/index.md

This way you will have a separate table containing the references.

Comment: Thanks this is also something I was trying to use, finally I just filter the values in a loop.